# Append to a class attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, addclass

I'm working on a multistep form with jquery and I'm trying to add classes to keep count of the formsteps that I have. Currently my Jquery is adding step-0, step-1 etc. classes to every .step class.

But I want to append the i counter to the .step class that is already there having a single attribute instead of adding an entire class atttribute and having 2 attributes. Although it must be simple I can't really find how to do this cleanly.

HTML:

```
<!--multistep form-->
<form id="multistepform" method="post">
    <div class="step">
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
    </div>

    <div class="step">
        First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
        Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" value="submit data">
    </div>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var steps = $("#multistepform .step");

    var count = steps.length;

    steps.each(function(i) {
        $(this).addClass("step-" + i);
    })

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify a class, but instead remove `.step` and add `.step-<i>` class

```
steps.each(function(i) {
    $(this).removeClass('step').addClass("step-" + i);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't provide a UI to modify the name of a class.

Add a new one and remove the old one instead.

```
steps.each(function(i) {
    var el = $(this);
    el.addClass("step-" + i);
    el.removeClass("step");
})
```

Comment: Good thing to know you can't modify the classname. Thanks for helping out.